# How to keep selection on radio buttons after clicking previous button

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, radio-button

For my Quiz app, i am creating 4 custom radio buttons for 4 answers by setting active and inactive images . When i select the button the state changing to active but when i press previous button the state going to inactive .

Code for creating Custom buttons

> ```
>     //answer 1
>     targetLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
>     CGSize labelSize = CGSizeMake(240, 9999);
>     CGSize theStringSize = [ans1 sizeWithFont:targetLabel.font          constrainedToSize:labelSize lineBreakMode:targetLabel.lineBreakMode];
>     targetLabel.frame = CGRectMake(targetLabel0.frame.origin.x+40, targetLabel0.frame.size.height+40, theStringSize.width, theStringSize.height);
>     targetLabel.text = ans1;
>     [targetLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
>     targetLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
>     [targetLabel sizeToFit];
>     [scroll addSubview:targetLabel];
>     // button 1
>  ans1btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,targetLabel.frame.origin.y-5,30,30)];
>     ans1btn.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
>      [ans1btn setSelected:NO];
>     [ans1btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gray.png"]
>                        forState:UIControlStateNormal];
>     [ans1btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"green.png"]
>                        forState:UIControlStateSelected];
>     ans1btn.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted=YES;
>     [ans1btn addTarget:self
>                 action:@selector(checkboxSelected:)
>       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
>     ans1btn.tag=1;
>     [scroll addSubview:ans1btn];
> ```

Calling method

```
-(void)checkboxSelected:(id)sender
{
checkBoxSelected = TRUE;
[ans1btn setSelected:checkBoxSelected];
if(checkBoxSelected==TRUE)
{
    checkBoxSelected1=FALSE;
    [ans1btn1 setSelected:checkBoxSelected1];
    [ans1btn2 setSelected:checkBoxSelected1];
    [ans1btn3 setSelected:checkBoxSelected1];
    checkBoxSelected=TRUE;
    targetLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    targetLabel1.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
    targetLabel2.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
    targetLabel3.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"the button is not selected");
}
}
```

Like that i am calling other button actions also

Can anyone please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not really understand your issue.

Comment: Please provide information about the implementation of the radio-buttons. Are you using a publicly available control or your own? Also check that you've implemented the MVC-pattern correctly and look into your model: Does it provide the ability to store previous answers? Does your controller correctly fetch and restore them to the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no actual radio button in iOS but you can use the following code to do what you want,

First, second, third and fourthButtonTags are values those already have been set in .xib or .m file. Specific numbers are also can be used.

In your .h file;

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *firstButton, *secondButton, *thirdButton, *fourthButton;
```

In your .m file;

```
- (IBAction)buttonSelection:(id)sender {
    UIButton *senderButton = (UIButton *) sender;

    if (senderButton.tag == firstButtonTag) {
        if (_firstButton.selected) {
            _firstButton.selected = NO;
        }
        else {
            _firstButton.selected = YES;
            _secondButton.selected = NO;
            _thirdButton.selected = NO;
            _fourthButton.selected = NO;
        }
    }
    else if (senderButton.tag == secondButtonTag) {
        if (_secondButton.selected) {
            _secondButton.selected = NO;
        }
        else {
            _secondButton.selected = YES;
            _firstButton.selected = NO;
            _thirdButton.selected = NO;
            _fourthButton.selected = NO;
        }
    }
    else if (senderButton.tag == thirdButtonTag) {
        if (_thirdButton.selected) {
            _thirdButton.selected = NO;
        }
        else {
            _thirdButton.selected = YES;
            _firstButton.selected = NO;
            _secondButton.selected = NO;
            _fourthButton.selected = NO;
        }
    }
    else if (senderButton.tag == fourthButtonTag) {
        if (_fourthButton.selected) {
            _fourthButton.selected = NO;
        }
        else {
            _fourthButton.selected = YES;
            _firstButton.selected = NO;
            _secondButton.selected = NO;
            _thirdButton.selected = NO;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer . Actually my problem is ... its a Quiz app. On View added 1 textview for question , 4 buttons( radio buttons ) for selecting answers, Next and previous buttons for moving forward and backward. After selecting one answer for 1st question moving to second  question when i come back for first question , the selected answer going to inactive state. How to keep selected answer in selected state only when we move front and back.

Comment: You can save the button state for all the answered questions. Such as, for each question you can keep a plist and set the state for all four buttons and load the view up to those buttons states.

Comment: Once again thanks..i solved the problem .. instead of taking plist i took dictionary and set tag values for particular question .. its solved my problem thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

try like this ,here define one button globally and play with that button,no need to take tag and all other stuff

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)UIButton *previousSelectedBtn;

- (IBAction)radioButtonSelection:(UIButton *)sender {
    sender.selected=YES;
    if(_previousSelectedBtn)
        _previousSelectedBtn.selected=NO;
    _previousSelectedBtn=sender;

}
```